# Can the middle element in set of integers modulo n be an element of the multiplicative group?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n>3$ be even.

If we consider $\frac{n}{2}$ we know that it belongs to $Z/nZ$ but does it also belong to $(Z/nZ)^*$,    (the multiplicative group of integers modulo n)?

I'm thinking no but cannot prove it.

Comment: If $n\ge 4$ is even, then $\frac{n}{2}\in(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ if and only if $\gcd\left(\frac{n}{2},n\right)=1$, which is impossible (because $\gcd\left(\frac{n}{2},n\right)=\frac{n}{2}\ge 2$).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Suppose we are given an integer $x$, and we wish to determine whether $\overline{x} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.  If it were, then we could find an integer $y$ such that $xy \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.  In other words, $n$ divides $xy - 1 \implies nm = xy - 1$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Rearranging the above yields $xy - nm = 1$.  Meditate on the implications of this expression.

Answer (score 0):

If $\dfrac{n}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^\times$, then $a\dfrac{n}{2}\equiv 1 \bmod n$ for some $a$. This implies $0 \equiv 2 \bmod n$ and so $n=2$.